# Redirect an image path to root level

Tags: image, .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a cakephp 2.x website in a subfolder Public_html/cake/
I want to show an image in the root server (public_html) whithout using http or https

Public_html/cake/images/logo.png should become Public_html/images/logo.png

Any idea how to make this wit htaccess or else ?

```
src="<?php echo $this->webroot;?>images/logo.png
```

will give :

```
Public_html/cake/images/logo.png
```

I need to be :

```
Public_html/images/logo.png
```

One folder upon
I don't want to use http because the website will be http and also https which give a security warning if it has http content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of code:

```
src="<?php echo $this->webroot;?>images/logo.png
```

Is not how template files in a CakePHP project are expected to be written. There are many [helper classes](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html) which make generating html markup easier.

### Generating an img tag

To generate an image tag use [the Html Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::image)

> Creates a formatted image tag. The path supplied should be relative to
>   `/app/webroot/img/`.
>
> ```
> echo $html->image('cake_logo.png', array('alt' => 'CakePHP'));
> ```
>
> Will output:
>
> ```
> <img src="/img/cake_logo.png" alt="CakePHP" />
> ```

This method, as with all methods that generate a url, accounts for whether the application is installed in a subfolder or not, so it'll work with no changes whether the application is installed on `http://example.com`, `http://example.com/folder` OR `http://localhost/MyProject` etc.

If passed a path starting with a forward slash, this is *relative* to where the application is installed. With an install in the `Public_html` folder this code:

```
echo $html->image('/images/logo.png');
```

would generate:

```
<img src="/Public_html/images/logo.png" alt="" />
```

### Getting just the url

To get just the url, use [the assetUrl method](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.next/lib/Cake/View/Helper.php#L337-L380):

```
// Outputs /img/logo.png
echo $html->assetUrl('logo.png');
```

This is the method the HtmlHelper calls to get the path/url to put in the `src` attribute of an image tag.

### Be conventional

CakePHP expects images to be in a folder named `img` not `images`, which is why none of the docs exactly match your current usage.

If you'd rather keep images where they are, you can configure the application such that usage matches the documentation by defining the [`imageBaseUrl` configuration setting](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.next/app/Config/core.php#L123-L127).

Answer (score 0):

Insert this rule as your first redirect rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^cake/(images/.+)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: It is not appropriate to solve the question asked with a rewrite rule (generating the wrong url, and handling that with mod rewrite, instead of just generating the right url in the first place).